# Can powershell compare if statement to table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write an if statement that compares to a list.  Not sure if PS can do it without writing a Multiple nested if statements.

```
If ($number){
Option1 do option1;
Option2 do Option2;
Option3 do option3
}
Else {
Do final Option}
```

Sorry, I have been trying to find something, but not certain what to even search for.

Comment: This is called a switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is a [**switch** statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6):

```
$Number = 2
switch ($Number){
    1{
        "HELLO"
    }
    2{
        "WORLD"
    }
    3{
        "ABCEFG"
    }
    default{
        "Nothing Here"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It is much easier to find information once you know what the command is called.  My question got down voted, and did not have a clue what to look for.    Thanks again.

Comment: No Problem. Goodluck